# Do while loop with If statement that adds a value when condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I'm looking into a do while loop to enter a number on `cellcert, 4`, and return a value on `cellcert,5`. However, if the `cellcert, 4` value is more than 1, it will add 5 for every "1's" so it has the If logic below:

1 = 18, 2 = 18+5, 3 = 18+5+5, 4 = 18+5+5+5 and so on...

This is why I'm looking into incorporating separate function(s) to do the adding of 5 code and call it within `Sub TATcomputation()`

```vb
Sub TATcomputation()

    Dim certcell As Integer
    certcell = 2

    Do While Cells(certcell, 4).Value <> ""
        Cells(certcell, 5).Value = Cells(certcell, 4).Value * 18
        certcell = certcell + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you adding 5? To what variable or cell? Is this separate from your logic for something to be multiplied by 18 or should that only happen when the value is 1?

Comment: Hi! thanks for asking! YEs, 18 should only happen when the value of the cell is 1, but if the value is more than 1, it should add another 5. 

If I input 1 on the cell, it should give the other cell 18. If I enter 2, it should give me 23 because every additional 1 should add +5.  It doesn't have to multiply it by 18 again, just add 5. 

1=18
2 = (18)+5
3 = (18)+(5)+(5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a `IF` statement here. Just always start with 18 and then multiply your cell value in `Column D` *(less one)* by 5

```
'Do While....
    Cells(certvalue, 5).Value = 18 + ((Cells(certvalue, 4) -1) *5)
    'certvalue = cervalue + 1
'Loop
```

---

You should qualify those `Cells` objects or use a `With` block btw

Comment: I guess this won't work if you can have values that are negative or `0`

Comment: Omg this works!! thank you so much! I just had to figure out if the number is 0 but thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub TATcomputation()

Dim certcell As Integer
certcell = 2

Do While Cells(certcell, 4).Value <> ""
    
    If certcell = 2 Then
        Cells(certcell, 5).Value = Cells(certcell, 4).Value * 18
    Else
        Cells(certcell, 5).Value = Cells(certcell, 4).Value * (18 + (5 * (certcell - 2)))
    End If
    certcell = certcell + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It's almost close to what I need, just tweaking it a little bit!